# JMS bridge in Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: jms, tibco-ems, spring-cloud-dataflow

How can I setup a JMS bridge in Spring Cloud Dataflow between a topic in one server to some other topic in another server?

My problem is that there is a JMS source, but I don't know how to setup the server address/username/password (I'm using Tibco EMS). Another issue is that I don't see any JMS sink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream's JMS-binder implementation is under [incubation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms/milestone/1). We are aiming to release a milestone shortly after Spring Cloud Stream's [Chelsea.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-starters/milestones).

With this binder implementation in the classpath, you could build apps to produce or consume from JMS based messaging middlewares.

Given the license requirements, TIBCO EMS probably require a custom implementation of this binder similar to [IBM MQ](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq) or [Solace](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-solace) - please feel free to submit a proposal and/or a pull request against [JMS-binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms/issues) repo.

Once we have the binder implementation, you could then directly interact with backing JMS queue/topic in Spring Cloud Data Flow via [explicit-broker-destinations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-explicit-destination-names). You don't need a JMS source/sink application in this model; instead, you can directly publish/subscribe to named channels.

Comment: Using explicit-broker-destinations can you interact with different JMS servers? If yes, how? How such a stream definition would look like?

Comment: You'd supply default JMS server configurations at SCDF-server level and all the apps orchestrated via SCDF would automatically receive it - refer to [global app settings section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-global-properties). On the explicit destination scenario, given you've already configured the JMS server, and for a given stream e.g.,: `stream create foo --definition ":mysourceTopic > hdfs"`, the `hdfs` app would receive the payload directly from `mySourceTopic`.

Comment: That's because the `hdfs` app (_a consumer in this case_) is bundled with `jms-binder` and it had received the JMS server credentials from SCDF automatically.

Comment: And how can I send from a JMS topic to a Kafka topic?

Comment: Similar to JMS binder specs, you could define many other cluster configurations including different binder implementations. I tried to summarize in this [GH-issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/rabbit/issues/1#issuecomment-287509751) recently. You could define `rabbitBinder`, `rabbitBinder1`, `jmsTestBinder` or `kafkaBinder` etc., To produce and consume from different messaging systems, you would have to use the OOTB `bridge-processor`. To this app, you would supply producer and consumer binder configurations at the stream deploy time.

Comment: This is what we use internally when you create a stream with just the destinations directly; for example: `"myjmssourcetopic > :mykafkasinktopic"`, but this stream assumes interacting with same messaging middleware with same configs. Since your case involves different messaging systems altogether, you'd have to manually override the producer and consumer configurations. It'd be something like: `stream create foo --definition ":myjmssourcetopic > bridge --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder= jmsTestBinder --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder= kafkaBinder ... > :mykafkasinktopic"`.